# Flipping bitmap without creating new bitmaps

Tags: java, android

I want to flip a bitmap that moves around with canvas or any other tool that does not contain creating new bitmaps. I managed to flip the bitmap with this code:

```
    c.save();
    c.scale(-1, 1,screenw/2,screenh/2);
    c.drawBitmap(mob, position.x,position.y,null);
    c.restore();
```

But that also flips the position of the bitmap, meaning that if it was moving left, after flipping it - it will move right. I don't want that, I want the position to be moving the same, only that the bitmap will be flipped. Any ideas?

Comment: tried scaling the Matrix?

Comment: @pskink wont the result be the same? you just rescale the whole matrix with -1 as well as you do to the canvas, and that will also change the position i believe

Comment: if you don't try you will not know

Comment: @pskink tried, position is still wrong

Comment: @pskink I've found a fix for the matrix solution, ill post it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Draw(Canvas c){
        UpdateAll();
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setScale(-1, 1,mob.getWidth()/2,mob.getHeight()/2); 
        m.postTranslate(position.x, position.y);
        c.drawBitmap(mob,m,null);
    }
```

the mob is the bitmap, make sure to create the Matrix outside the draw function unlike in this code.